# Exoplayer activity, volume cannot adjust

Tags: android, android-activity, exoplayer, dialogfragment

Volume control is not possible in exoplayer activity

There is an activity that plays music with exoplayer from Android.
Press a button in the activity to run bottomdialogfragment and adjust the playback time, but if you press the volume button here, it does not adjust. what is the problem